# How to generate Graphql types for React with help of graphql-codegen when Apollo Server is in production mode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo, graphql-codegen

When backend mode set to `NODE_ENV: development` all works perfectly, but in production mode graphql-codegen fails with error:

**Local web-server error:**

> GraphQL introspection is not allowed by Apollo Server, but the query
> contained _schema or _type. To enable introspection, pass
> introspection: true to ApolloServer in production

**Production web-server error:**

> Failed to load schema from https://example.com/graphql, reason: unable
> to verify the first certificate. GraphQL Code Generator supports:
>
> - ES Modules and CommonJS exports (export as default or named export "schema")
> - Introspection JSON File
> - URL of GraphQL endpoint
> - Multiple files with type definitions (glob expressions)
> - String in config file

**Front-end codegen.yml:**

```yaml
schema: ${REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL}
documents:
 - './src/GraphQL/queries/query.ts'    
 - './src/GraphQL/mutations/mutation.ts'
overwrite: true
generates:
  ./src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
    config:
      skipTypename: false
      withHooks: true
      withHOC: false
      withComponent: false
```

**Front-end devDependencies:**

```json
{
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.20.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.20.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.17.14",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
}
```

npm scripts:

```json
{
    "generate": "graphql-codegen -r dotenv/config --watch --config codegen.yml",
    "prebuild": "graphql-codegen -r dotenv/config --config codegen.yml"
}
```

**./src/generated/** directory added to .gitignore

Comment: ask API/server maintainers about providing downloadable/static pregenerated [on build/deploy] schema file

Answer (score 0):

My solution was in add introspection plugin and separate codegen.yml file into:

- **codegen-generate-schema-json** and
- **codegen-generate-typescript**

```json
devDependencies: {"@graphql-codegen/introspection": "^1.18.1"}
```

codegen-generate-typescript.yml:

```yaml
schema: graphql.schema.json
documents:
  - './src/GraphQL/queries/query.ts'
  - './src/GraphQL/mutations/mutation.ts'
overwrite: true
generates:
  ./src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
    config:
      skipTypename: false
      withHooks: true
      withHOC: false
      withComponent: false
```

codegen-generate-schema-json.yml:

```yaml
schema: ${REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL}
overwrite: true
generates:
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - introspection
```

So **./graphql.schema.json** file need to be commited and used as schema source instead of URI.

Maybe you suggest the better solution?

Comment: Or you can just commit generated.tsx